# Pull Image Url From RSS FEED

Tags: javascript, rss, google-feed-api

I'm using the following code to display to parse an RSS feed via Javascript and Google Feed API into HTML. Is it possible to grab an image from the RSS feed? It is working fine fro the title, snippet, date and link. I just need the URL for the image as well.

```
    function myGetElementsByClassName(selector) {
    if ( document.getElementsByClassName ) {
        return document.getElementsByClassName(selector);
    }

    var returnList = new Array();
    var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    var max = nodes.length;
    for ( var i = 0; i < max; i++ ) {
        if ( nodes[i].className == selector ) {
            returnList[returnList.length] = nodes[i];
        }
    }
    return returnList;
}

var rssReader = {
    containers : null,

    // initialization function
    init : function(selector) {
        containers = myGetElementsByClassName(selector);
        for(i=0;i<containers.length;i++){
            // getting necessary variables
            var rssUrl = containers[i].getAttribute('rss_url');
            var num = containers[i].getAttribute('rss_num');
            var id = containers[i].getAttribute('id');
            // creating temp scripts which will help us to transform XML (RSS) to JSON
            var url = encodeURIComponent(rssUrl);
            var googUrl = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num='+num+'&q='+url+'&callback=rssReader.parse&context='+id;

            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
            script.setAttribute('charset','utf-8');
            script.setAttribute('src',googUrl);
            containers[i].appendChild(script);
        }
    },

    // parsing of results by google
    parse : function(context, data) {
        var container = document.getElementById(context);
        container.innerHTML = '';

        // creating list of elements
        var mainList = document.createElement('ul');

        // also creating its childs (subitems)
        var entries = data.feed.entries;
        for (var i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
            var listItem = document.createElement('li');
            var title = entries[i].title;
            var publishedDate  = entries[i]. publishedDate;
            var contentSnippet = entries[i].contentSnippet;
            var contentSnippetText = document.createTextNode(contentSnippet);
            var mediaGroup = entries[i].mediaGroup;
            var link = document.createElement('a');
            link.setAttribute('href', entries[i].link);
            link.setAttribute('target','_blank');
            var text = document.createTextNode(title);
            link.appendChild(text);

            var text = document.createTextNode(publishedDate);
            link.appendChild(text);


                var text = document.createTextNode(mediaGroup);
            link.appendChild(text);

            // add link to list item
            listItem.appendChild(link);

            var desc = document.createElement('p');
            desc.appendChild(contentSnippetText);

            // add description to list item
            listItem.appendChild(desc);

            // adding list item to main list
            mainList.appendChild(listItem);
        }
        container.appendChild(mainList);
    }
};

window.onload = function() {
    rssReader.init('post_results');
}



<div class="post_results" id="post_results2" rss_num="2" rss_url="http://www.feed.com/feed">
        <div class="loading_rss">
            <img alt="Loading..." src="images/loading.gif" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to pull the content (which houses the image tag) with:            var

```
content = entries[i].content;
```

And parse that to get just the image using this:

```
   var input = content;
            var div = document.createElement('div');

            div.innerHTML = input;

            var img = div.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
```